# Doctrine 2: Is there a way to inherit mapping from a trait using yaml or xml?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I found the [following example in the doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/tutorials/override-field-association-mappings-in-subclasses.html) where they have added mapping to a trait:

```
/**
 * Trait class
 */
trait ExampleTrait
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="string") */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Column(name="trait_foo", type="integer", length=100, nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    protected $foo;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Bar", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
     * @JoinColumn(name="example_trait_bar_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $bar;
}
```

I am trying to map a trait without having to duplicate the mapping in the classes that inherit it. I haven't honestly tried this above as my current project is using yaml for mapping but it looks like a regular php class would inherit the mapping as well when using the trait.

Is there a way to inherit the mapping for this trait without using associations but using yaml or xml instead? I tried setting the trait as a [mapped superclass](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) but it didn't work but I am basically looking for the same type of idea.

Thanks.

Comment: it'sworking out of the box. you simply forgot the @MappedSuperclass annotation.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I found to achieve a mapped trait is by using a subscriber. The following should work for your example, and it's easily customizable:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber\Doctrine;

use App\Model\Bar;
use App\Model\ExampleTrait;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo;

final class ResolveTraitSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            Events::loadClassMetadata,
        ];
    }

    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $methods = [
            ExampleTrait::class => [$this, 'addExampleTrait'],
            // add more traits if needed...
        ];

        $metadata = $args->getClassMetadata();
        $traits = (array) $metadata->reflClass?->getTraits();

        foreach ($traits as $trait) {
            $name = $trait->getName();
            if (isset($methods[$name])) {
                $methods[$name]($metadata);
            }
        }
    }

    private function addExampleTrait(ClassMetadataInfo $metadata): void
    {
        $metadata->mapField([
            'fieldName' => 'id',
        ]);
        $metadata->mapField([
            'fieldName' => 'trait_foo',
            'length' => 100,
            'nullable' => true,
            'unique' => true,
        ]);
        $metadata->mapOneToOne([
            'targetEntity' => Bar::class,
            'cascade' => ['persist', 'merge'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to define it as a service, with the `doctrine.event_subscriber` tag.

Answer (score -1):

To declare mappedSupperClass with YAML:

```
Namespace\For\Your\MappingClass:
    type: mappedSuperclass
    fields:
        id:
            id:
                type: integer
                generator:
                    strategy: AUTO

        ... other fields and relations
```

To declare it with XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                  http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <mapped-superclass name="Namespace\For\Your\MappingClass">

        <field name="foo" column="foo" type="string" length="255" />

        <field name="bar" column="bar" type="string" length="255" unique="true" />

        ... other fields

    </mapped-superclass>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

If you run `app/console doctrine:generate:entities` you will be able to use mappedSuperClass as ascendant in other entities.

Comment: Unfortunately this is only working for classes, not for traits

Comment: @MassimilianoArione My answer was not to show how to map Traits but to show how to configure mappedSuperClass - this is the answer for the basic question "Is there a way to inherit the mapping for this trait without using associations but using yaml or xml instead?"

Comment: and so your answer was pretty useless since the mapped superclass configuration is shown in the link provided in the question

Comment: @MassimilianoArione The link to mapped superclass is provided with information that "it didn't work". So I've provided the way how it can be configured and processed as a confirmed and working way of using mapped superclass.

Comment: It didn't work because it doesn't work with traits, as I mentioned before. Your solution doesn't work with traits either. It works for classes, which 1) is not what was requested 2) was already provided in the link.

Comment: We have different perception of what is requested only. Besides it is already in the comment that it does work with mappedsupper class.